# How to run a Node.js script from PHP with XAMPP?

Tags: php, node.js, xampp, phantomjs, shell-exec

I am using XAMPP on Windows 7 to run a localhost, and I'm trying to use the PHP `exec` function to execute a Node.js script.

I am able to successfully use the `exec` function to run PhantomJS scripts, but when I try to do the same thing for Node.js, it doesn't work.

He's an example of a PHP script that properly runs a PhantomJS script:

```
<?php

  exec('/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /phantomjs/scripts/test.js', $output);
  print_r($output);
```

And here's a similar example of a Node.js script that outputs an empty array every time:

```
<?php

  exec('/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/node /Program Files (x86)/nodejs/test.js', $output);
  print_r($output);
```

I'm sure that all of my paths are correct and that the Node.js script executes correctly whenever I execute it directly from the command line, but I can't get anything to return from the Node.js script when I run it from the PHP `exec` command. I also tried the following script, but I still get nothing:

```
<?php

  exec('/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/node -v', $output);
  print_r($output);
```

Any advice on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would guess the issue is the spaces in the path, try escaping them with a backslash character: `/Program\ Files\ (x86)...`.  You may also need to double escape, to keep the backslash character in the string and send it to the shell, not sure: `/Program\\ Files\\ (x86)...`.

Comment: You were on the right track, but what ultimately worked was slightly different. I tried 1, 2, 3 even 4 backslashes to escape the spaces, and that didn't work, but I then put the full paths in double quotes and it worked fine. In other words, the following worked: `exec('"/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/node" "/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/test.js"', $output);`. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I will gladly accept it. Thanks.